# How to efficiently center (mean-shift) a spark RowMatrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-algebra

I'm wondering what would be an efficient way of centering the
data of a RowMatrix in spark efficiently (for large inputs), do libraries
 or functions already exist to do this?
So far I'm thinking of just defining a function and then using map to subtract
the mean, but is this efficient?

I want to do that in order to afterward perform an SVD (to do PCA) on
the given matrix.

EDIT :
here I found something that does the mean shift by the previously mentioned method (using map) :

```
def subPairs = (vPair: (Double, Double)) => vPair._1 - vPair._2
def subMean = (v: Vector) => Vectors.dense(v.toArray.zip(mean.toArray).map(subPairs))
 val stdData = rows.map(subMean)
```

source : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17907/commits/956ce87cd151a9b30d181618aad7ef2a7ee859dc

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share example data and code?\

Comment: I supplied an example found on github, whats concerning me is that the reviewer of this github explicitly say it is an unefficient mean-shifting method.

Answer (score 1):

Extract rows:

```
val mat: RowMatrix = ???
val rows = mat.rows
```

Fit `StadardScalerModel`

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.StandardScaler

val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = false).fit(rows)
```

Scale

```
scaler.transform(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see in the code of StandartScaler that it uses treeAggregate and so is distributed if im not mistaken. The question that remains is if its faster than using map, since map probably does some smart things as well, maybe I could just try and see which way is faster (memory also being important).

Comment: StandardScaler does not seem satisfying for sparse matrices, which is what I tried on (sparse data stored in a rowmatrix). The first singular value is off by a lot as a result.

Comment: You can do map alone. The reduction is required to find the mean.

Comment: you can have the mean of a rowmatrix using summary.mean